# Why is strsplit not working with my character string?

Tags: r, string, list, palindrome, strsplit

I wanted to combine R's rev() function and strsplit function to check if a string is a palindrome. My idea was to use strsplit() to split up my character string into individual letters and then use rev on the result to reverse the order of the letters. So, say:

```
a = "summer"
```

and we do:

```
b = strsplit(a,"")
```

We get:

```
[[1]]
[1] "s" "u" "m" "m" "e" "r"
```

Looks like it should work. But use rev on this:

```
rev(b)
```

and the output doesn't change:

```
[[1]]
[1] "s" "u" "m" "m" "e" "r"
```

Now, I've narrowed down the answer to have something to do with the '[[1]]', which I recognise as list notation. If we do:

c = strsplit(a,"")[[1]]

We get:

[1] "s" "u" "m" "m" "e" "r"

i.e. no '[[1]]'. Now, if we use rev(c) here, we get the desired result:

```
[1] "r" "e" "m" "m" "u" "s"
```

Similarly, if we have:

```
d = 1:10
```

and use rev(d), we get:

```
[1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

What both of the successful attempts have in common is the lack of list notation. Could anybody enlighten me as to how R is treating our initial character string and why using list notation with strsplit allows us to utlise rev properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is happening here is that when you call `rev(b)`, you are reversing a *list* which has just one element in it.  That one element is a vector of characters.  So the reverse operation just returns the same thing:

```r
b <- strsplit(a, "")
rev(b)

[[1]]
[1] "s" "u" "m" "m" "e" "r"
```

However, when you access the first (and only) element of that list, you reverse the vector of letters:

```r
rev(b[[1]])

[1] "r" "e" "m" "m" "u" "s"
```

If you take a list with more than one element and reverse it, you will see the elements reverse:

```r
lst <- list(a=c("v", "x"), b=c("y", "z"))
lst

$a
[1] "v" "x"

$b
[1] "y" "z"

rev(lst)

$b
[1] "y" "z"

$a
[1] "v" "x"
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this. You answer is very clarifying. I have one question: the initial character string ("summer") isn't a list. It only becomes a list after we have used strsplit on it. How then does the list notation work with strsplit? i.e. why does it work to do strsplit(a,"")[[1]] when a isn't a list?

Comment: In `strsplit(a,"")[[1]]` the call to `strsplit()` returns a list, and then the first element of this list is accessed using `[[1]]`.  This first (and only) list element is a vector of all characters in the original input string `a`.